# How to read data from serial-to-usb device?

Tags: bash, serial-port, usbserial

I have a sensor device connected to my Ubuntu 20 machine using a serial to usb cable. I understand that to stream data from it I need to run the following commands:

1. Enter root with `sudo -I`.
2. Setup a virtual COM port with `stty -F /dev/ttyACM0 9600 cs8 -cstopb -parenb`.
3. Send a command to the device to initiate data streaming with `echo -e "some_string" > /dev/ttyACM0`.
4. Stream data with `cat < /dev/ttyACM0`.

However, I cannot be sure that my device is connected as `/dev/ttyACM0`. How can I set this up? Currently it has the path `/dev/bus/usb/001/005`, although the last number changes every time the device is plugged in.

In response to the comment below, here is the output I get when I disconnect the device and run `dmesg | tail` (I've edited some real values):

```
[89092.291151] usb 1-1: USB disconnect, device number 11
[89100.310893] usb 1-1: new full-speed USB device number 12 using xhci_hcd
[89100.467562] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=SOME_ID, idProduct=SOME_PRODUCT, bcdDevice=SOME_BCD_DEVICE
[89100.467565] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[89100.467567] usb 1-1: Product: SOME_PRODUCT
[89100.467569] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: SOME_MANUFACTURER
```

EDIT: I have just found that I can use `sudo modprobe usbserial vendor=SOME_ID product=SOME_PRODUCT`  to make `ttyUSB0` available. However, plugging this into the above commands and running `screen /dev/ttyUSB0` only returns lots of ``` characters. Note that this stops when the device is unplugged.

Comment: Your device is most likely at `/dev/ttyUSBx` with x being a number starting by 0. If you only have one, it will be `/dev/ttyUSB0`

Comment: Thanks for the comment! This does not seem to exist. Any idea why?

Comment: Plug in the USB *"cable"*, and then enter the command `dmesg | tail`.  Hopefully the last line will be something like `[12415. ...] usb i-j: xyz  now attached to ttyXXX0`.  Append the output to your post if you need more help.

Comment: Just added this - see above. Doesn't look like I get the expected output...

Comment: You’ll want to make a udev rule so that it shows up as the same port every time.  This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55581196/624483

Comment: @Pyy -- Obliterating the product information from the messages negates the purpose. The messages are now useless, and convey no information.  If that's all the messages, then it appears that there is no device driver available to service that USB device.  When there's no device driver, there would be no need to create any device node in **/dev**, i.e there are no major & minor numbers (from the driver) to assign to the node.

Comment: Yes that was all the message from dmesg | tail. I've just added an edit that allows me to get the device loaded as ttyUSB0 but I still can't return data. Does that give any clues about whether a driver is installed? Where might I get a driver from?

Comment: *"Where might I get a driver from?"* -- Talk to *"SOME_MANUFACTURER"* about their *"SOME_PRODUCT"*.  Or read **Documentation/usb/usb-serial.rst**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get this working. The commands were:

```
sudo -i
rmmod ftdi_sio
rmmod usbserial
modprobe ftdi-sio
echo -n VENDOR_ID PRODUCT_ID | sudo tee /sys/bus/usb-serial/drivers/ftdi_sio/new_id
stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0 9600 cs8 -cstopb -parenb
echo -e "uud1\r" > /dev/ttyUSB0
screen /dev/ttyUSB0 9600
```